# Realm Object Server population, costs, sync

Tags: react-native, realm

I have a simple app that pulls jobs in from a server and has two way sync App<-->Server. The jobs need to be able to be populated into either the App or the server.

Is there anyway for me to create this infrastructure using realm/react-native without paying $1500 a month?

I'd really like to use realm for this project but there is no way I can afford that much. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It almost sounds like something you would be able to achieve with the developer edition which is free. With "populate", are we talking 1000's of jobs? And is that a one time task or continuous?

If you make react native app that operates with the Realm Object Server, you can have a special admin UI in it that uses an admin user, which would enable you to update a realm with new jobs.

If you need code running on the server to continuously update the jobs etc., it is probably not achievable with the developer edition as it stands today. You could set up a mac to do so but that is probably not feasible.

Comment: Yes you can, but that admin data access requires a professional license which I cannot afford. This would need continuous synchronisation.